# DNS not responding with IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, windows-server-2012

I have 4 windows servers running 2012. One of them is a domain controller and the other 3 are connected to the domain. They all have static IP addresses ranging from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.4, their DNS server is set to 10.0.0.1 which is the domain controller and DNS server. I can disconnect and rejoin the domain at any time without any issues. But when I ping the Servers using computer names I get Could not locate host, except for the server running on 10.0.0.2 (called iis) so ping iis returns the ip address but ping sql returns could not find host sql but when I type ping -a 10.0.0.4 then after a small delay it returns Pinging SQL [10.0.0.4] and then receive 4 replies.

nslookup on server running DNS:

[image: nslookup]

nslookup on one of the other servers in the network:

[image]

nslookup on server named sql

[image]

ipconfig /all output

[image]

EDIT:

netstat does not list the internal network card of the servers I can't ping using their names

Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: What do you get when you do a nslookup?

Comment: @Sane I don't understand the nslookup command

Comment: nslookup [name of server] [ip of dns server]

Comment: @Sane I have updated the NSLookup screenshot

Comment: What do you get if you do the nslookup on the server that you can't ping?

Comment: It looks like you're using short names (no dot) in your `ping` tests and not fully qualified names. Short names only work so long as all of the machines on your network contain the same list of "DNS search suffixes", i.e. the list of suffixes to try appending to the end of those short names. Make sure this configuration is consistent.

Comment: Based on your latest screenshot, it looks like you need to double check and make sure that you really are using the same DNS server on both machines. `nslookup` suggests that it would have returned the right answer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output for the command "ipconfig /all" on one of the servers that can't ping.

Comment: @AndrewB I just added them and still not working, now only the domain controller running the DNS server is resolving the names, other servers still not doing it, for some reason they can all ping the server called IIS

Comment: @Sane added screenshot

Comment: Have you checked the Firewall to see if it is blocking ICMP from all the computers except the one that can ping it.

Comment: @Sane I turned of windows firewall on all 4 servers before I posted the question

Comment: I know Andrew was talking about short names and FQDN, did you try pinging using the FQDN: ping sql.ad.ik.io, if that doesn't work I would try disabling IPv6 on the servers and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Short names will not be your problem at this point. Please refer to my second comment, beginning with "Based on your latest screenshot".

Comment: @Sane I have removed IPv6 from all 4 servers, and restarted them, still not working

Comment: @AndrewB They all have the exact same DNS settings, just verified it now

Comment: Sorry to say I have no idea at this point.

Comment: @Sane check new edit

Comment: Are the servers virtual servers?

Comment: This may be a case of negative caching. Does `ipconfig /flushdns` fix the problem? (run this on the machine experiencing the problem, not the DNS server)

Comment: @AndrewB makes not difference

Comment: @Sane yes they are but they their public facing network adapters have been disabled. I have a DirectAccess server running on that network and I use remote desktop to connect to the server, the one called IIS, and then from there I can access the other servers

Comment: Did you try pinging using the FQDN? ex. ping sql.ad.ik.io

Comment: @Sane Yes I did try that

Comment: And the result? and for some reason do you have WINS enabled in your domain?

Comment: @Sane Ping request could not find host sql.ad.ik.io. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: And if you ping using the -4 command (ping -4 sql.ad.ik.io and ping -4 sql) at this point I'm taking shots in the dark.

Comment: Sorry guys, comments are not meant to be a discussion forum. Please take it to [chat] if you want to discuss it further.